# typo3 delete cache of fe plugin with every new request

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have some very specific problem in typo3. Here is the situation :

I got fe extension, part of it is plugin, which is displayed in fe and it says, whether user is logged or not (or not registered, disabled, there are many possibilities).

This plugin is displayed in some "dummy" hiden page and then injected into master template through typoscript (CONTENT object).

I need get rid of t3 caching featueres, I need, that this plugin source code is executed with every request user will make.

I tried to disable cache through known options, set pi_USER_INT =1 property in plugin class, tried to use COA_INT for loading content, but plugin content is still cached for some request, I think, that cache is linked to logged user (but this is not acceptable).

Any ideas, how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

If COA_INT does not help, then think about Proxy-Cache or Browser-Cache. COA_INT is uncached - but if there is no request to your webserver, you will not get an update.

Perhaps add

```
config.additionalHeaders = Cache-Control: no-cache
```

so you would prevent caching. If this works, you know that the issue is on the client side.

Comment: No, that won't do any good, because I do want content to be cached. I figured out exact place in source, where caching is taking place (tslib_fe). Now I'm trying to find out a way to alter cache hash id, which will solve my problem. But thats probably not posible without altering typo3 source and I must avoid that :-/

Comment: Maybe it's not clear from my question, so : 1. whole page html is always cached in memcache, 2. page contains plugin, which shouldn't be cached

Comment: figured it out. Only thing needed was to turn off cache, when calling t3lib_extMgm::addPItoST43 method.

Comment: with the method i mentioned, you would avoid browser-caching, not TYPO3 cacheing!